# Editing aesthetics of my Histogram in R

Tags: r, editor, histogram

I made this code

```
RendBio= RtBio
m<-mean(RtBio)
std<-sqrt(var(RtBio))
hist(RendBio, density=20, prob=TRUE,
     xlab="Rendimientos Bio Pappel", ylim=c(0, 20), 
     main="normal curve over histogram", col="brown1")
curve(dnorm(x, mean=m, sd=std), 
      col="darkgoldenrod1", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")
```

When I run the code there are lines in my histogram but I'd like it to be filled with e solid color. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is because `density` controls the spacing between "shading lines", not the transparency of the color. See the documentation for `hist(...)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want transparency then you need to use an argument to rgb with the same values as `col2rgb("brown1")` but with an alpha argument:

```
col2rgb("brown1")
      [,1]
red    255
green   64
blue    64
# Since you want to have transparency of 20% use maxColorValue=1
rgb( 1,.25,.25, .2)
[1] "#FF404033"
```

Try:

```
hist(RendBio,  prob=TRUE,
     xlab="Rendimientos Bio Pappel", ylim=c(0, 20), 
     main="normal curve over histogram", col=rgb( 1,.25,.25, .2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

So my comment above explains the problem, but does not provide a solution. Here's a solution.

```
RendBio <- RtBio <- rnorm(1000,5,2)
m       <- mean(RtBio)
std     <- sqrt(var(RtBio))   # can just use sd(...) for this...
hist(RendBio, prob=TRUE, ylim=c(0,.2),
     xlab="Rendimientos Bio Pappel",  
     main="normal curve over histogram", 
     col=rgb(matrix(col2rgb("brown1"),ncol=3),alpha=50,maxColorValue=255))
curve(dnorm(x, mean=m, sd=std), 
      col="darkgoldenrod1", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")
```

[image]

As the other answer explains, you need to use the `rgb(...)` function with an `alpha=...` argument. The hard part is doing that while still using the color names (e.g. "brown1").

**EDIT** Evidently, this requires more explanation, based on the comment.

The `rgb(...)` function requires *separate arguments* for the three color channels, e.g.

```
rgb(red=..., blue=..., green=..., ...)
```

whereas `col2rgb(...)` returns a *vector of length 3*, containing the r, g, and b values. So this fails:

```
rgb(col2rgb("brown1"))
# Error in rgb(col2rgb("brown1")) : at least 3 columns needed
```

The error refers to the fact that `rgb(...)` will take a *matrix with 3 columns* as argument, returning a vector of colors with one color for each row of the matrix. So one way to do this is to convert the output of `col2rgb(...)` to a matrix with 1 row and 3 columns:

```
rgb(matrix(col2rgb("brown1"),ncol=3),alpha=50,maxColorValue=255)
# [1] "#FF404032"
```

Very convoluted, but it does work. If someone has a better way, I'd love to see it. You can of course just manually display the r,g,b values from `col2rgb(...)`, and then type these into a call to `rgb(...)`, but this approach lacks generality (try putting it into a function with "brown1" as the argument).

The point of the `ggplot` solution below is to show that you can avoid all this business of manipulating rgb values, and just use `alpha=...` directly.

Same thing using `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- data.frame(x=RendBio)
ggplot(gg,aes(x=x))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),color="grey50",fill="brown1",alpha=.2, binwidth=1)+
  stat_function(fun=dnorm,args=list(mean=m,sd=std), color="darkgoldenrod1",size=1)+
  labs(x="Rendimientos Bio Pappel", title="normal curve over histogram")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

In `ggplot` an enclosed polygon (like the bars in the histogram) is colored by specifying `fill=...`, while `color=...` specifies the outline color. For linear geometries (like the curve), `color=...` specifies the color of the curve.

Comment: I don't understand why it is "hard" to get the r,g,b values from `col2rgb("brown1")` after I gave the code.