# how can I control the alpha setting in R when using the points function?

Tags: r, plot, point, alpha, shiny

I'm creating an interactive Shiny app -- I have a widget (a slider) that retrieves an alpha parameter from the user.  The user can select an alpha value between 0.0 and 1.0

My app is all set up, however, and when I went back to add the alpha to the plot, I am shocked to see that when adding points to a plot in R, the `points` function doesn't have a parameter for alpha.

I can create nice points here:

`points(DF$x_values, DF$y_values, pch=20, cex=2, col="springgreen4")`

but I can't add any sort of `alpha` parameter to the call!

Surely I'm not the only person to find this.  Does anyone know the reasoning behind this lack of functionality, or even better...has anyone found a good work around?

Comment: If you're saying that the inputs are "springgreen4" and an alpha value, the approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301811/editing-aesthetics-of-my-histogram-in-r/23303001#23303001) will work: `col=rgb(matrix(col2rgb("springgreen4")/255,ncol=3),alpha=0.5,maxColorValue=1)`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995683/any-way-to-make-plot-points-in-scatterplot-more-transparent-in-r

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use rgb() to specify color so you can control alpha:

```
plot(1:5, cex = 0)
points(1:5, pch=20, cex=2, col = rgb(0, 1, 0, c(0.1,0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)))
```

In your example:

```
points(DF$x_values, DF$y_values, pch=20, cex=2, col = rgb(0, 1, 0, alpha))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I've edited my question to be a little more informative.  I'm working with Shiny....so I need a single value as input, that can change.

Comment: absolutely perfect.  Thanks!!

Comment: `do.call(rgb,c(as.list(col2rgb("springgreen4")/255),alpha))` will aid you in changing from named colours to rgb representations too.

Comment: thelatemail -- I was just struggling with this! Thanks so much for your help.